.NET 6 / Entity Framework Core: why extra Context Factory in migrations project?
I maintain a .NET 6 project with this structure:
Api
 |
 +-- Api.csproj       <--- references Migrations project
 +-- Program.cs       <--- adds context factory as a service
 |
 +-- Migrations
      +-- Migrations.csproj    <- includes "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design",
                                           "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite"
      +-- MyContext.cs
      +-- ContextFactory.cs    <- required by dotnet ef migrations

The Migrations project has its own ContextFactory (method CreateDbContext()), which is only needed by dotnet ef migrations add when run in this project's directory to create the migrations classes. Works so far.
In the parent project, the factory is added with:
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlite(configuration.GetConnectionString("DbFileName"));
    });

So I assume that .NET 6 does the job for me, and I do not need any further factory; and it also does not reference the factory from the Migrations project. The only thing is that I have now two places to say options.UseSqlite() / optionsBuilder.UseSqlite() which seems to be redundant. And I have a class that is only needed for setup, not the project itself.
My goal is to get rid of the extra factory, to have only one place that say options.UseSqlite().
However, when I remove the extra factory and call dotnet ef migrations add in the parent directory, it breaks with an error. It seems that EF tools do not recognize that a factory is implemented under the hood (so I assume). When I run it in the Migrations project, it misses its factory, of course.
The error message is this:

Our target project 'Api' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'Migrations'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Api")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.

I don't see where in the Migrations project I should add some DbContextOptionsBuilder, because I did options.UseSqlServer() already in the parent project and do no longer want it in the factory class (that I want to get rid of).
Question: is there a way to get rid of the factory class in the Migrations project?
Edit: here is the factory class code:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

public class ContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(args[0]);
        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}


There's no "parent project" when you run migrations. The line services.AddDbContextFactor is executed only when you run your main application, when the entire host/web app starts. The dotnet migrations tool knows nothing about it. You have to tell it where the actual database is.

I do tell it the database by calling dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -- "Data Source=../MyDatabase.db". Still, it is missing its factory , or maybe something that is derived from IDesignTimeDbContextFactory. When I remove the factory, it errors: "Unable to create an object of type 'MyContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728"
(I will add the factory class above)

You don't tell it what database to use though - SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? MySQL?

I did: UseSqlite(). But I think it's the same with others (I have just migrated the whole stuff from Postgres to Sqlite). The only difference is the call options.UseSqlite(...) vs. options.UseNpgsql(...). And of course the connection string. In both cases, this needs to be called during application startup - and in the factory.
